# external trigger to perform action in media player app using Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am looking for a way to use an external trigger via the USB "Lightning" connector of an iphone to play the next song in my music player app.  At this point I just want to register to a trigger event.  Does anyone have any insights on how to do this?  I don't even know where to start for something like this.

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? When someone connect something to the lightning port?

Comment: I need a method to connect a switch to the lightning port that triggers a song change.  The solution will include both hardware and software

Comment: You may need MFi. Since with headset you can change music with I don't know which profile, you may simulate it.

Comment: You are correct.  Problem is when we use the headset to trigger the next song the output gets switched to the headphones instead of the BLE device.  What is the MFi?

Comment: Made For iPhone. The output to the BLE ? You're streaming Audio through BLE?

Comment: Yes it's complicated

Comment: Streaming audio a BLE audio device